NMCLI: create a bridge interface with a member that is a vlanned subinterface
There are tons of docs out there claiming to do this:
https://docs.redhat.com/en/documentation/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/configuring_and_managing_networking/configuring-a-network-bridge_configuring-and-managing-networking#configuring-a-network-bridge-by-using-nmcli_configuring-a-network-bridge
https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-add-network-bridge-with-nmcli-networkmanager-on-linux/
... and others, But none seem to work with my setup that also uses nmcli, where this server has multiple ip interfaces all from a vlan off the main interface enp0s31f6
For example here I have this one:
nmcli con add type vlan con-name eth5 ifname eth5 dev enp0s31f6 id 405 ip4 192.168.5.249/24 
and as soon as I create that I can then ARP and see all my cameras on that vlan 405.  So that works.  But then I want a local bridge that I can add that eth5 to.  Ive followed a number of different guides there, none seems to work.
Now at one point there, bumbling around I actually did have a working setup, where then I saw all my camera ARP addresses off the br5 interface instead of the eth5 one, and the br5 also had the IP address on it as well instead of the eth5 one, likely through some combo of settings between guides and shear luck, but I havent been able to replicate it.
Hopefully some of you may know the voodoo?  Which direction should I be facing when I do my rain dance?  How many chicken bones should I throw?
UFW is inactive

So I gave up on nmcli and dumped NetworkManager, did it all in /etc/network/services and my bridge works fine like that.  Every time I give NM a chance it sucks.
